# Click on a item of the list to display a new page

Tags: php

I have a table named **forums**  with 4 fields: id_forum, title, theme, fk_user.

I have an overview over some elements below:

[image]
I would like to click on the element of the theme and recuperate only the pseudo on another page. Is it possible?

Here is my code PHP for the overview

```
<?php

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=exo', 'root', '');


$requestSQL = "SELECT forums.*, users.pseudo 
               FROM forums INNER JOIN users
               ON forums.fk_user=users.id_user 
               ORDER BY theme ASC";



$stm = $bdd->prepare($requestSQL);


$stm->execute();


?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Forum</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="title"><a href="view_forum.php"><h1>List forum</h1></a></div>
  </div>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<table id="tab">
<tr>
  <th>Id</th>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>Theme</th>
  <th>Pseudo</th>
</tr>

<?php

while($row = $stm->fetch()){ ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row ['id_forum'];?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $row ['title'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['pseudo'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}


?>

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How to add `<a href>` on my line `<td><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></td>` ?

I have tried this

```
<?php

while($row = $stm->fetch()){ ?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row ['id_forum'];?></td> 
  <td><a href="view_user">?php echo $row ['title'];?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $row ['theme'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['pseudo'];?></td>
</tr>

<?php

}

?>
```

My overview is catastrophic...

[image]

Comment: Well this is not PHP `<a href="view_user">?php echo $row ['title'];?></a>`  This is PHP `<a href="view_user"><?php echo $row ['title'];?></a>`  In that you omitted part of the `<?php` tag  (`<`)....  In other words a simple `typo`.

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix: ahahahha thank you ! I was really stuck.

Comment: Further I have no idea what this means `recuperate only the pseudo on another page`  But I imagine you may wish to pass something as part of the url query string so you can access it with `$_GET` (on that other page) such as `<a href="view_user?psudo=<?php echo $row['psudo']; ?>"><?php echo $row ['title'];?></a>`  Then you can use it with `$_GET['psudo']` after checking if it's set and what not....   Personally I would pass the row's ID, and then pull everything I need to from the DB on that other page. etc....

Comment: @ ArtisticPhoenix: It was just to know only. I am yet novice.

Comment: `I am yet novice` everyone was at some point, and even after almost 9 years of PHP I still find new and better ways to do stuff, you have to always look for ways to improve your code.  Be lazy like me, and do more with less....

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix hihihih thank you for your advice.